# How to remove i:type="d:string" from PropertyInfo of SOAP in KSOAP2 Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I am using ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I am working on a project where i need the following soap request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mod="http://www.tmforum.org/xml/tip/model" xmlns:cust="http://www.tmforum.org/xml/tip/customer/cust">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mod:listProblemsRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mod:customer>

            <cust:iD >1100000677</cust:iD>
         </mod:customer>


      </mod:listProblemsRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but using KSOAP2 I am able to generate the following request:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
   <v:Body>
      <retrieveCustomerProfileRequest xmlns="http://www.tmforum.org/xml/tip/model">
           <n0:customer xmlns:n0="http://www.tmforum.org/xml/tip/model">
               <n1:iD i:type="d:string" xmlns:n1="http://www.tmforum.org/xml/tip/customer      /cust">1100000990</n1:iD> 
   </n0:customer>
   </retrieveCustomerProfileRequest>
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

How do I remove `i:type="d:string"` from the SOAP request.

Please suggest a solution or any Workaround that could be done in Source code of KSOAP2 so that I may be able to generate the appropriate request.

Comment: Can't you consume `Soap` service without `KSoap` Library? Does it necessary to use?

Comment: @AndroidVogue..yes bcoz the SOAP Response i am getting is highly complex to parse so i need ksoap..

Comment: You can parse your complex response using `XML Parsers` available Like `SAXParser` `XMLPullParser` `DOMParser` if you are getting response in `XML` and if `JSON` response still you can handle it with Android. I handled my `SOAP` Service without `KSOAP` Library and it is working very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a workaround to my problem in ksoap :

```
1. Download the source code of Ksoap2.jar.
2.open up Transport .java and edit its :

    protected byte[] createRequestData(SoapEnvelope envelope, String encoding)
                throws IOException  

Method.

3.i edited it as follows:


protected byte[] createRequestData(SoapEnvelope envelope, String encoding)
            throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bufferLength);
        byte result[] = null;
        bos.write(xmlVersionTag.getBytes());
        XmlSerializer xw = new KXmlSerializer();
        xw.setOutput(bos, encoding);
        envelope.write(xw);
        xw.flush();
        bos.write('\r');
        bos.write('\n');
        bos.flush();
        result = bos.toByteArray();
        xw = null;
        bos = null;


        String requestObject = new String(result);
        String pattern = "i:type=\"d:string\"";

        String resultString="";

        System.out.println("==earlier String==" + requestObject);
        if (requestObject.contains(pattern)) {

            System.out.println("==is it here ");
            resultString=requestObject.replace(pattern, "");

}

4.compile this class using classpath of ksoap2.jar
5.extract the ksoap2.jar and remove existing transport.class from it.
6.Add newly compiled .class file and make a new jar.
7.import the jar in your project.
Problem solved..
```

Comment: Is not necesary to have all the library compiled... Only is necesary two classes, HttpTransportSE.java and  Transport.java. instead of recompile  just copy these to your class package. 

import the classes from your package and edit like the answer of amritpal.   HttpTransportSE extends of Transport.
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new ttpTransportSE(url,timeOut);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set these `soap` envelope properties:

```
    soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
```

And in the `getPropertyInfo` for the object when returning the property info for the field make sure that you set the correct type e.g. :

```
    info.type = field.getClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you are creating

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope sEnvelop;
```

just assign `sEnvelop.implicitTypes = true;`

it will not create `"i:type="d:string"" or "i:type="d:long""` inner datatype tag and web service can execute successfully